# Chef: Skip install if amazon-ssm-agent-2.2.355.0-1.x86_64 already exists

Tags: chef-infra

How to skip the install of ssm agent if the agent "amazon-ssm-agent-2.2.355.0-1.x86_64" already exists on the machine?

Here's my cookbook:

```
remote_file '/tmp/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm' do
  source 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/SMAgent/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm'
  action :create
  notifies :run, 'execute[amazon-ssm-agent-install]', :immediately
end

execute 'amazon-ssm-agent-install' do
  command 'rpm -ivh /tmp/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm'
  action :nothing
  rpm -qa | grep ssm
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `rpm_package` resource instead. That understands how to check for a package already.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `package` resource or one of it's related resources, in this case `rpm_package`, would be the optimal way to handle this particular case. However, you should look at the [Guards](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#not-if-examples) for Chef resources.

In your case `rpm -qa | grep ssm` is the right command but you need to use a `not_if` guard in order to prevent the installation. For example:

`not_if 'rpm -qa | grep ssm'`

When a string is passed to a guard it's run as a shell command. The result of the shell command (`true` or `false`) determines whether or not the resource will run based on the guard type (`only_if` the guard returns true or `not_if` the guard returns true). You should also familiarize yourself with the different options for [Guard Interpreters](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guard-interpreters) since shell scripts are not the only option.